# NodeJS - How do I make from python 'for _ in range(number)' in NodeJS/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

In python3x I'm using a simple code:

```
for i in range(1, 10):
    print(i)
```

I tried using Array function on NodeJS/JavaScript:

```
const LIST = [];
const Range = Array(10).fill("0, 10", 0, 10)
LIST.push(Range);

console.log(LIST);
```

But it seems it just gonna give output:

```
[
  [
    '0, 10', '0, 10',
    '0, 10', '0, 10',
    '0, 10', '0, 10',
    '0, 10', '0, 10',
    '0, 10', '0, 10'
  ]
]
```

How do I make it gives output from 1 to 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why... not just use [a plain `for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)?

```
for(let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array()` fills the array with nothing but gives it a certain length, so filling it with null makes it `[null, null, ...]`. Mapping the array is similar to mapping in python, you loop through each item in the array and return the current index + 1. That creates an array `[1, 2, 3, 4 ..., 10]`

```js
const Range = Array(10).fill(null).map((_, i) => i + 1);

console.log(Range);
```

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent to `for i in range(x, y)` is `for (let i = x; i < y; i++)`:

```js
for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
  console.log(i)
}
```

Output is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 just as it was in your Python example.

See [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).

Answer (score 0):

In short, what you're describing is an array where the index is also the value. That can be achieved with this little line:

```js
const array = Array(10).fill(0).map((zero, index) => index)

console.log(array) // [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]
```

In short, it does this:

1. `Array(10)`: Make an array of length 10, which is empty.
2. `.fill(0)`: Fill the array with zeros (could be anything).
3. `.map((z, i) => i)`: Replace each value (zero) with its index (0, 1, 2...)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
[...Array(10).keys()].map(x => x + 1);
```

Explanation:

- `Array(10)` gives an array of length 10.
- `.keys()` gives the indices viz 0, 1, 2, ... 9.
- `.map(...)` increments each index by 1, thus giving 1, 2, 3, ... 10

Try it out:

```js
console.log([...Array(10).keys()].map(x => x + 1))
```